# MySQL query using alias to count certain years from DATETIME

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I have a table which consists of an `ID` count, a `DATETIME` field named `orderDate` showing when a customer bought an item. I am trying to create a query which takes `ID` and `orderDate`, to find all dates which were ordered in 2015 using an alias and count them.

For example, my output table should contain IDs and a count of all the orders placed in 2015 for that `ID` in a single row.

My query, which I have been using to try make it work with very little success is:

```
SELECT ID,YEAR(orderDate) as lastyear 
from t1 
HAVING lastyear = 2015
```

I am aware that I cannot use `WHERE`, so it's a case of using `HAVING`, but I cannot for the life of me right now figure out how to use the alias to count.

I am using MySQL 5.1.

Comment: Something like this? `SELECT id, 2015 AS last_year, COUNT(*) AS order_count
FROM t1
WHERE orderDate >= MAKEDATE(2015, 1)
AND   orderDate  < MAKEDATE(2016, 1) 
GROUP BY id ;`

Comment: Follow-up question: [Query to extract Month/Year from specific month/year and Count them using an Alias](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/156798)

Answer (score 1):

This query will work for any given year based on today

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 100;
SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(orderDate ORDER BY orderDate) orderDates,COUNT(1) orderCount
FROM t1
WHERE orderDate >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1,1)
AND   orderDate <= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
GROUP BY ID;
```

Running this query now will give you all of 2015.

Running this query next year will give you all of 2016.

## NOTES

`MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1,1)` gives you the first day of last year

`MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) - INTERVAL 1 DAY` gives you the last day of last year

The reason I use

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024 * 100;
```

The default for [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) is 1024 (1K). I set it to 100M in case the list is long.

This query will work faster if you have a comound index on `(ID,orderDate)`

If you do not have such an index, then create one:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 ADD INDEX ID_orderDate_ndx (ID,orderDate);
```

## COMMENTARY ON YOUR QUESTION

With regard to your original query

- You cannot use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY` in the strictest sense ([See MySQL Documentation on MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html))
- There is no need for `HAVING`

  - `HAVING` is the same as a `WHERE` except it is against an aggregated set of data.
  - Using `WHERE` just gets the data before aggregation
- Using `HAVING` complicates the query because you would have to structure the query for counting multiple years and then select just `2015`. Using `WHERE` gets data only from 2015. Then, you can aggregate by `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the answer I gave to a question on Stack Overflow some time ago:

[Select all months within given date span, including the ones with 0 values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093924/select-all-months-within-given-date-span-including-the-ones-with-0-values/3111441#3111441)

You can use something similar and either join to the date dimension table using `date(orderDate) = dateTable.myDate` or preferably split your datetime field into separate date and time fields, then you get maximum flexibility.